# Angular: Convert base64 string to Byte Array in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, base64

I am trying to convert a `base64` string to byte array and open it as a `pdf` file in IE. The only problem is `atob` is not supported in IE, so trying to use Buffer like this:

```
let b64Data = myBase64Url.split(',', 2)[1];
var byteArray = new Buffer(b64Data ,'base64').toString('binary');
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
```

I am getting a popup successfully to open the file

[image]

But the file is corrupted

[image]

What am i doing wrong ? Is there a better way to convert `base64` to byte array in IE ?

Comment: Is `myBase64Url` just plain base64 data, or is it prepended with the mime type? What issue were you having with `atob`?

Comment: atob is not supported in IE. My base64 URL is prepended with pdf mimetype

Comment: That's the problem-- the mime type will need to be removed before this will work.

Comment: Removed the mimetype and , tried the same code. Only better thing is its opening a blank pdf file. Couldn't see any data. See updated code in the question.

Comment: You may need to remove `.toString('binary');` as well

Comment: yes that worked. Can you post this as an answer, will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the base64 to be properly decoded, it must be *only* the base64 data, i.e. no mimetype information preceding it.

You will also need to remove `.toString('binary')` so that you're passing a buffer instead of a string.